# overload operator[][] for 2d vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

so currently i have to write a program in c++ where i have to create a class "CMyMatrix" and i wanted to know if its possible to overload the operator: "[][]"(i think technically they are 2 operators?)
im using a 2d vector and would like the operator to work the same way as it works if you create a 2d array.

```
class CMyMatrix {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
    int row_M = 0;
    int column_N = 0;
public:
    double& operator[][](int M, int N) { return something };
};
```

thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: There's no `operator[][]()` function, you could overload directly.

Comment: You could have `operator[]` return a proxy object that has its own `operator[]` that accesses the underlying member variable.  Alternatively, you could use `operator()(int M, int N)` if accessing it as a functor is acceptably.  And if C++23, see the answer below.

Comment: You might want to consider what would happen if your `CMyMatrix` class simply had `std::vector<double> &operator[] (int M) { return matrix[M]; }`.

Answer (score 2):

This couldn't be done before C++23 since `operator[]` must have exactly one argument.

With the adoption of the [multidimensional subscript operator](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2128r6.pdf) in C++23, now you can

```
#include <vector>

class CMyMatrix {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<double>> matrix;
    int row_M = 0;
    int column_N = 0;
public:
    double& operator[](int M, int N) { return matrix[M][N]; };
};

int main() {
  CMyMatrix m;
  m[0, 1] = 0.42;
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/afoT7YY56)